# My Google Compute Engine instances hang during boot using the v1 API

Tags: google-compute-engine

In the serial console, I see:

```
<snip>
Booting from Hard Disk...
Booting from 0000:7c00
```

… instance hangs

Specifically creating the instance with the `v1` API results in a hang:

```
API_VERSION = 'v1'
gce_service = build('compute', API_VERSION)
...
request = gce_service.instances().insert(
       project=PROJECT_ID, body=instance, zone=DEFAULT_ZONE)
```

While creating the instance with the `v1beta16` API boots successfully:

```
API_VERSION = 'v1beta16'
gce_service = build('compute', API_VERSION)
...
request = gce_service.instances().insert(
   project=PROJECT_ID, body=instance, zone=DEFAULT_ZONE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may experience this issue because of changes in how kernels are handled in the `v1` API compared to the `v1beta16` API. In `v1beta16`, Compute Engine injected a Google-supplied kernel at boot time. As of `v1`, Compute Engine now uses stock kernels from the boot image or persistent disk. This allows far more flexibility, but does require a one time manual step to update persistent disks and images created before `v1`. You can use the detailed steps provided in the [transition guide](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/transition-v1#customkernelbinaries) to help you update your disk or image.

If you just need to start your instances quickly, you can use the deprecated `v1beta16` API to do so. Example using `gcutil`:

```
$ gcutil addinstance INSTANCE_NAME --disk=DISK_NAME,boot --service_version=v1beta16
```